# ¿Por qué entra siempre en el IF?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este pequeño código y no funciona como debe. Siempre entra en el IF, ¡por qué?

```
var recortar = prompt("Dime tu palabra");
var letra = prompt("Dime la letra de ruptura");
var posicion;
var pos = [];
var j = 0;
var posic = 0;
while (posicion != -1) {
    posicion = recortar.indexOf(letra);
    if (posicion == -1) {
        alert("No está");
        break;
    } else {
        posicion = recortar.indexOf(letra);
        posic = posic + posicion + 1;
        pos[j] = posic;
        j++;
        recortar = recortar.substring(posicion + 1);
    }
}
for (i in pos) {
    alert(pos[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

El problema está en que no paras el bucle while y vas recortando el contenido de la variable `recortar`. De este modo, siempre acaba entrando en el `if (posicion == -1)`.

Por ejemplo, insertas la palabra **colorado** y como letra la **l**. Te encuentra la **l** y recorta la palabra colorado de modo que queda solo **orado**, el loop sigue y en la siguiente iteración ya no encuentra la **l** y te muestra el alert **No está**.

Si haces esto con la letra **o** por ejemplo, la encuentra 3 veces y luego te muestra "No está". En cualquier caso, siempre te lo muestra.

Desconozco cuando quieres parar realmente. Añado unas trazas a tu código para que lo entiendas mejor:

```js
var recortar = prompt("Dime tu palabra");
var letra = prompt("Dime la letra de ruptura");
var posicion;
var pos = [];
var j = 0;
var posic = 0;
while (posicion != -1) {
    posicion = recortar.indexOf(letra);    
    if (posicion == -1) {
        console.log("if: " + posicion + ", recortar: '" + recortar + "'");
        alert("No está");
        break;
    } else {
        posicion = recortar.indexOf(letra);        
        posic = posic + posicion + 1;
        pos[j] = posic;
        j++;
        recortar = recortar.substring(posicion + 1);
        console.log("else: " + posicion + ", recortar: '" + recortar + "'");
    }
}
for (i in pos) {
    alert(pos[i]);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.Hacía justo lo que le pedía y yo no me enteraba.