# leer información de un array

Tags: javascript

Buenos días,

Me surge una duda con el siguiente código de javascript

```
var equipo1=["team1","10","100"];
var equipo2=["team2","20","100"];
var equipo3=["team3","5","100"];
var ordenpuntos=[];

for(i=1;i<4;i++){
ordenpuntos.push("equipo"+i+"[1]")}
alert(ordenpuntos)
```

Mi intención es meter en el array ordenpuntos el segundo campo de cada array equipoX pero la función `.push()` en el recorrido del `for`, me identifica los resultados `equipo1[1],equipo2[1] y equipo3[1]` como texto y no como la variable para que añada el campo correspondiente, por lo que, el resultado obtenido provisionalmente en el `alert` no es `(10,20,5)` sino `(equipo1[1],equipo2[1] y equipo3[1])`

Comment: Hola Gema, recuerda marcar una de las respuestas como aceptada si te ha servido, si no explica qué mas necesitas. Y tambien [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/62422/por-qu%C3%A9-entra-siempre-en-el-if) necesita aceptacion (le agradeciste al usuario su solucion asi que supongo que te valió). [Como aceptar respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que te propongo es la siguiente:
Tu partes de tener 3 equipos,

```
var equipo1=["team1","10","100"];
var equipo2=["team2","20","100"];
var equipo3=["team3","5","100"];
```

Pero... ¿Qué sucedería si tuvieras 100?, supongo que de alguna forma vendrán los datos de la base de datos y si no, te recomiendo para facilitarte el flujo o trabajo de los mismos, almacenarlos todos en 1 solo **`array`** como verás a continuación:

```
var arrEquipos = [["team1","10","100"],["team2","20","100"],["team3","5","100"]];
```

De esta forma te será mucho mas simple almacenar lo que quieras como si de filas se trataran.

Como cada equipo tiene su propio nombre: *team1, team2, team3*... Siempre puedes acceder al valor 0, de cada elemento del **`array`** que será su nombre, romper con el o dividirlo en team + 1 y obtener el numero 1 para identificar a modo de índice o diccionario que estas en el primer equipo o elemento del **`array`** global.

Generas tu **`array`** de puntos:

```
var ordenpuntos = [];
```

Ahora aquí, primero, al añadir .length, te da igual la longitud que tenga el array general, pues se recorre segun el tamaño del array.
`for(i=0; i < arrEquipos.length; i++){`

Primero accedes a cada elemento del array general, utilizando la variable `i`:

```
 ('team1','10','100'),('team...
```

Seguidamente que accedes al valor que buscas dentro de cada elemento:

```
0 = teamX
1 = 'XX'
2 = 'XXX'
ordenpuntos.push(arrEquipos[i][1]);
}

alert(ordenpuntos);
```

El resultado es un **`array`**:

> `(10,20,5)`

Answer (score 3):

Tu fallo está en que metes el string `"equipo"+i+"[1]"` en vez de el contenido del elemento

Te recomiendo crear un objeto `equipos` y meter cada uno de ellos ahi.

Sería:

```js
var equipos = {
  equipo1 : ["team1", "10", "100"],
  equipo2 : ["team2", "20", "100"],
  equipo3 : ["team3", "5", "100"]
}
var ordenpuntos = [];

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  ordenpuntos.push(equipos["equipo"+ i][1])
}
console.log(ordenpuntos)
```

Si es imperativo tener cada equipo en una variable aparte puedes hacer uso de

```
window['nombrevariable']
```

```js
var equipo1 = ["team1", "10", "100"];
var equipo2 = ["team2", "20", "100"];
var equipo3 = ["team3", "5", "100"];

var ordenpuntos = [];

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  ordenpuntos.push(window["equipo" + i][1])
}
console.log(ordenpuntos)
```